# Django REST framework: How can I associate with other model in POST request?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm really new to creating API and I might misunderstand a lot. I want to associate an object with other model in POST request as I do when posting as a form data in astual site. How can I do using rest framework?

my api view is like this

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def list_comment(request, pk):
"""
List all comments that belong to an entry or add a comment to the entry
"""
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, id=pk)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(entry=entry)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = CommentSerializer(comments, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CommentSerializer(data=request.data)
        # I want to associate the comment with 'entry' here
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Also the rest framework page's [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmCVa.png) is kind of hard to experiment something and I want to change it to form. How can I change it? Even if I select form data, the content form doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use create method in serializer class, and do create action on there,

This is an example from www.django-rest-framework.org

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Comment(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.content = validated_data.get('content', instance.content)
        instance.created = validated_data.get('created', instance.created)
        return instance
```